# Find points between the curve which is draw by given points

Tags: ios, math, graph, charts

I have a task to draw a curve path via given points. I done by using the CGMutablepath to finish this job. But some point of time I need to find the 'y' point based on giving 'x' point to show value. I attached the sample image below.
[image]

The points which I have shown as black dots. I need to find a 'y' point if I give 'x' which is somewhere lies in the path. If anyone knows the solution please help me.

Comment: How that resulting `CGMutablepath` is described? Perhaps you have formula/expression/equation for every path part.

Comment: What type of curve is this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the cubic function. I referred to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLmEsBYHcwA)

```
//
//  CubicFunction.swift
//
//  Created by Karthik Venkatesh on 30/08/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 karthik. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import Accelerate

extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}

class CubicFunction {

    var matrix_a = [[CGFloat]]()
    var matrix_b = [CGFloat]()

    var coefficients = [CGFloat]()

    init(withPoints points: [CGPoint]) {
        self.constructMatrixA(forXValues: points.map{ $0.x })
        let matrixAItemsPerRow = matrix_a.first?.count ?? 0
        self.constructMatrixB(forXValues: points.map{ $0.y })
        var matrix_a_1d = [CGFloat]()
        for row in matrix_a { matrix_a_1d.append(contentsOf: row) }
        let inversed = self.invert(matrix: matrix_a_1d.map{ Double($0) }).map{ CGFloat($0) }
        let inversed_matrix = inversed.chunked(into: matrixAItemsPerRow)
        self.coefficients.append(contentsOf: self.multiply(matrixA: inversed_matrix, matrixB: matrix_b))
   }

   private func constructMatrixA(forXValues values: [CGFloat]) {
        for value in values {
            var row = [CGFloat]()
            for i in stride(from: values.count - 1, to: 0, by: -1) {
                row.append(pow(value,CGFloat(i)))
            }
            row.append(1)
            matrix_a.append(row)
        }
    }

    private func constructMatrixB(forXValues values: [CGFloat]) {
        self.matrix_b.append(contentsOf: values)
    }

    private func invert(matrix : [Double]) -> [Double] {
        var inMatrix = matrix
        var N = __CLPK_integer(sqrt(Double(matrix.count)))
        var pivots = [__CLPK_integer](repeating: 0, count: Int(N))
        var workspace = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: Int(N))
        var error : __CLPK_integer = 0

        withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &N) {
            dgetrf_($0, $0, &inMatrix, $0, &pivots, &error)
            dgetri_($0, &inMatrix, $0, &pivots, &workspace, $0, &error)
        }
        return inMatrix
    }

    private func multiply(matrixA: [[CGFloat]], matrixB: [CGFloat]) -> [CGFloat] {
        if matrixA[0].count != matrixB.count { return [] }
        var result: [CGFloat] = [CGFloat]()
        for i in 0..<matrixA.count {
            let row = matrixA[i]
            var value: CGFloat = 0
            for j in 0..<row.count {
                value = value + (row[j] * matrixB[j])
            }
            result.append(value)
        }
        return result
    }

    func y(forX x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat? {
        var y: CGFloat? = nil
        for index in 0..<self.coefficients.count {
            y = (y ?? 0) + (self.coefficients[index] * pow(x, CGFloat(self.coefficients.count - 1 - index)))
        }
        return y
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You most probably have a piecewise parametric interpolant, i.e. of the form

```
x(t) = Pi(t),
y(t) = Qi(t)
```

where `Pi`, `Qi` are polynomials of which the coefficients are known.

If you specify an `x`, you must solve the equation `x = Pi(t)` for `i` and `t`. To find `i` you need to know the ranges of the `Pi` (not too difficult for a polynomial). Then when you have `i`, you must solve a polynomial equation. That's fine for cubic curves, problematic for higher degrees.

Depending on the data, there might be several solutions for `i` and `t`.

Then when you know `t`, compute `y(t)`.